# Navigating through email to my website, logs me out of my website

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending a link to the email address in laravel, the link is  mywebsite.com/notifications, 
When I open email and "Click" on that link, it redirects me to mywebsite.com(Home page) but not to mywebsite.com/notifications and if I'm logged in, it logs me out of my website as well.

When I'm in the website and navigate within my website, notification pages/routes are working perfectly fine, it just has to be something related to route coming from email.

PS. I had just "auth" middleware applied on notifications routes, I even tried to move all notification routes out of "auth" but it's same
Plus Here is my env if that helps

```
APP_NAME=*********
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://devlocal.co
APP_TIMEZONE='Asia/Karachi'

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOCALE=ar

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=*********
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD='*********'

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=****

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=********************
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="*************"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="*****"

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"~
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

CACHE_DATABASE= 2
CACHE_VERSION= 12

SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false

MAX_INVALID_TRIES=2
MAX_INVALID_TRIES_TIMEOUT=4
```

Comment: You will have to explain to us how hitting a link in your email is any different from entering the same link in your browser. As far as I know these actions are the same. Now we don't have your email, so we can't see what the link is, nor can we test anything, so finding out what's what is going to be difficult. It could be something as basic as a link starting with 'http://`' instead of 'https://' combined with a routing problem. Who knows?

Comment: this is link copied from email http://mywebsite.com/notifications
and this is the link that works fine and hits within my site http://mywebsite.com/notifications

Both looks same, p.s. I've intentionally changed mywebsite.com here..

Comment: I understand that you want us to concentrate on the `/notifications` bit of the URL, but you've already looked at that, and it didn't solve the problem. I don't think we can be of any help, simply because there's no obvious reason, given in your question, why the link in the email does what it does.